# Check string in an array

Tags: vb.net, isnumeric

I have strings stored in an array and need to check if the 5th character of each string is a number or not. The code I used is:

```
If Mid(arr(i), 5, 1) = IsNumeric(True) Then
      MsgBox("Number")
End If
```

It is giving an error:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidCastException' occurred in Microsoft.VisualBasic.dll
>
> Additional information: Conversion from string "" to type 'Boolean' is not valid.

Comment: `Conversion from string "" to type 'Boolean' is not valid.` is a straight problem. You are passing a `boolean` to the function (true) instead of a object that can be evaluated as a number... that's your real problem. Also turn `Option Strict On`, it's your friend..

Comment: @Zaggler that's *one* problem.

Comment: I know, but that's the error. When that is addressed he has more... 

Answer (score 3):

You originally tagged your question as [vba](/questions/tagged/vba), but VBA doesn't throw `System.InvalidCastException`, or any other exception for that matter; [vb.net](/questions/tagged/vb.net) does.

`IsNumeric(True)` returns `True` if `True` is numeric. You want to verify if *the string retrieved from the array* is numeric; give it *the string retrieved from the array* as a parameter:

```
If IsNumeric(Mid(arr(i), 4, 1)) Then
    MsgBox("Number")
End If
```

Your code reads like VB6/VBA though, because of this:

```
Imports Microsoft.VisualBasic
```

That namespace contains VB6-like things that you don't need to use at all. The beauty of .net is that *everything is an object*, so assuming the array is an array of `String`, you can call the actual `String` instance methods instead of VB6's `Mid` function.

```
Dim theFifthCharacter As String = arr(i).Substring(4, 1)
```

Or, because you're only interested in 1 character, and a `String` is itself an `IEnumerable(Of Char)`, you can do this:

```
Dim theFifthCharacter As Char = arr(i)(4)
```

Notice the off-by-one - in .net indices start at 0, so if you want the 5th item you'll fetch index 4.

Now, if you want to see if it's numeric, you can *try* to *parse* it:

```
Dim digitValue As Integer
If Int32.TryParse(theFifthCharacter, digitValue) Then
    'numeric: digitValue contains the numeric value
Else
    'non-numeric: digitValue contains an Integer's default value (0)
End If
```

Lastly, if you want a message box, use WinForms' `MessageBox` instead of VB6's `MsgBox`:

```
Dim digitValue As Integer
If Int32.TryParse(theFifthCharacter, digitValue) Then
    'numeric: digitValue contains the numeric value
    MessageBox.Show(string.Format("Number: {0}", digitValue))
Else
    'non-numeric: digitValue contains an Integer's default value (0)
    MessageBox.Show("Not a number")
End If
```

Comment: Great explanation and detail!

Answer (score 1):

A more correct way to do this would be:

```
If Char.IsDigit(arr(i)(4)) Then
```

Comment: Seeing as this is idiomatic .net code that isn't using the VB6 rubbish in the `Microsoft.VisualBasic` namespace, I'm very curious about what the reason for the downvote here might be.

Comment: Using `Char.IsDigit()` allows some characters to return true and they are not even in the correct ASCII range. My opinion, `Integer.TryParse` is a better approach, ensures that it definitely falls between 0-9... Also explaining why the OP has that error would be useful so the OP can understand the problem.

Comment: @Zaggler, I think that you are confusing `Char.IsDigit` with `Char.IsNumber`.  According to the documentation, `IsDigit` will only match 0 - 9.

Comment: Char.IsDigit is a subset of Char.IsNumber... and depending on environment, some Thai symbols return as digit and it's wrong.. IsDigit can be useful but at the same time it doesn't hold up in cases.

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax is incorrect. It should be:

```
If IsNumeric(Mid(arr(i), 5, 1)) Then
```